# linking secondary dependencies in cross compilation

Tags: linux, linker, g++, cross-compiling, ld

I have a project that compiles on my target machine (nvidia jetson), and I am trying to cross-compile. I am stuck on a linking step, looking for secondary dependencies.

My build is failing on this step:

```
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ --sysroot=/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson -O2 -g -DNDEBUG CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/GetStatus.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Init.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Nack.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/StartProduction.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/AppData.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Counter.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Marker.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Program.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/RoboterSettings.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/LiveImage.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Format.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/VersionCheckVsPs.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_tcpAcceptor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_tcpStream.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_thread.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_init.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_status.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_productionState.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_app.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_program.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_liveImage.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_format.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_calibration.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_marker.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_versionCheckVsPs.cpp.o -o ../bin/VsCommunication  -Wl,-rpath,/home/lhahn/Documents/git/VisionSystem/build/lib:/usr/local/lib:/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu ../lib/libVsJsonParser.so ../lib/libRedisClient.so -lstdc++fs -pthread ../lib/libNanoLog.so /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so -lhiredis -lstdc++fs
```

with the error

```
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libz.so.1, needed by /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libm.so.6, needed by /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `deflate'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

for now I am focusing on the first problem, libz not being found.

I read [this](http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries.html) about secondary dependencies, and as far as I can tell libprotobuf.so is linked properly (see readelf output below) but the error message looks exactly like in the "dumb" example in the link above.

```
readelf -d libprotobuf.so

Dynamic section at offset 0x29ccd0 contains 32 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
...
```

Therefore, I tried linking like in the blog post "the correct way" as follows:

```
/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ --sysroot=/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson -O2 -g -DNDEBUG CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/GetStatus.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Init.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Nack.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/StartProduction.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/AppData.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Counter.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Marker.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Program.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/RoboterSettings.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/LiveImage.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/Format.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/VersionCheckVsPs.pb.cc.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_tcpAcceptor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_tcpStream.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_thread.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_init.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_status.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_productionState.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_app.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_program.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_liveImage.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_format.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_calibration.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_marker.cpp.o CMakeFiles/VsCommunication.dir/vs_c_versionCheckVsPs.cpp.o -o ../bin/VsCommunication  -Wl,-rpath,/home/lhahn/Documents/git/VisionSystem/build/lib:/usr/local/lib:/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu ../lib/libVsJsonParser.so ../lib/libRedisClient.so -lstdc++fs -pthread ../lib/libNanoLog.so /home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lhiredis -lstdc++fs
```

Notice the `-Wl,-rpath-link,/home/lhahn/Documents/CrossCompilation/Images/jetson/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu`, which should point the linker to the libz dependency.

However, I still get exactly the same result.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to what I'm missing